# Show that T(v) is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm stuck on a linear transformation problem

$T(v) = (v*z)z$ (* signifies dot product)

I have to show that 2 cases  hold $T(u+v) = T(u)+T(v)$ and $cT(v) = T(cv)$

Let $u$ be the vector (a,b) and $v$ be the vector (c,d)

$T(u+v)$ = 
\begin{bmatrix}a+c\\b+d\\\end{bmatrix}
$T(u+v)$  = $(((a+c)*z)z)$, $(((b+d)*z)z)$

$T(u)+T(v)$ = $(((a)*z)z), (((b)*z)z) + (((b)*z)z) , (((d)*z)z)$

I'm wondering if i'm going the right direction with this or am I completely off

Comment: z is some vector I suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that rather than writing out your vectors compent wise, you should use some of the properties of the dot product. For example

$T(u+v)=((u+v)*z)z=((u*z)+(v*z))z=(u*z)z+(v*z)z=T(u)+T(v)$

In the above line I used the fact that the dot product is linear in the first entry and I used the distribution property of scalar multiplication.

To show that $T$ preserves scalar multiplication you can use a similar argument. Can you see how?

Answer (score 0):

Let your $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ the transformation defined by:

$$T(\vec{v}) = \langle \vec{v},\vec z\rangle\vec z$$

For $\langle \vec{v},\vec z\rangle := v_1z_1+v_2z_2$ and $\vec z \in \mathbb{R}^2$ fixed. This what I understand by your question. Then we get that

> $$T(\vec v + \vec w) := \langle \vec v + \vec w,\vec z \rangle \vec z \stackrel{\text{definition of dot prod.}}{=} ((v_1+w_1)z_1+(v_2+w_2)z_2)\vec z \stackrel{\text{associativity + distributivity of } \mathbb{R}}{=} ((v_1z_1+v_2z_2)+(w_1z_1+w_2z_2))\vec z \\ \stackrel{\text{distributive}}{=}(v_1z_1+v_2z_2)\vec z + (w_1z_1+w_2z_2)\vec z \\\stackrel{\text{dot product definition}}= \langle\vec v, \vec z\rangle \vec z + \langle \vec w, \vec z \rangle \vec z =:T(v) + T(w) \tag{1}$$

Then we have that $T(\vec v + \vec w) = T(\vec v) + T(\vec w)$. Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ we can, using the above explanations for each step

> $$T(a\vec v) : = \langle a\vec v, \vec z \rangle \vec z = (av_1z_1+av_2z_2)\vec z = a(v_1z_1+v_2z_2)\vec z = a \langle \vec v, \vec z \rangle \vec z = aT(v)$$

Wich proves that $T(a \vec v) = aT(\vec v)$ $\forall a\in \mathbb{R}$.